# How to make reverse foregnkey/1to1/MtoM connections explicit in django models?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

Say there are two models like these:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    ...
class User(models.Model):
    posts = ManyToManyField(post, ...)
    ...
```

I know that Post.user is still available in the django querysets and I know about relatedname but there are cases where I also need to add field users to Post model, to which, if I remember correcly, django issues a warning.
In my case, I need to write a serializer (project uses DRF) for such implicit field, which is not possible (because "model Post doesn't have field users" to continue the example).

And even if it's ok to ignore warning and just make fields explicit, situation is still hard since MtoM is an reverse of MtoM and 1to1 is a reverse of 1to1 but there is no reverse to foreignKey.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement this in the serializer. You can implement this is:

```
class AccountSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = ['…']
```

and then we use that `AccountSerializer` in the `PostSerializer`:

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user_set = AccountSerializer(many=True)    

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['…']
```

Comment: I get TypeError at /api/posts
Direct assignment to the reverse side of a related set is prohibited. Use users.set() instead.

Comment: How do you *update* your model through the API view?

Comment: I don't, my views are GenericAPIViews with only get and post methods.